# Can you provide more suggestion on how == works in Java

Tags: java

I have below code

```
    String s1=new String("hello");  

    String s2="hello";  

    System.out.println(s1.hashCode());

    System.out.println(s2.hashCode());

    System.out.println(s1==s2); //returns false
```

Why do we get last statement as false ,the hashcode of s1 and s2 is same can someone please explain?

and after i do `String s3=s1.intern();`, `System.out.println(s2==s3);` returns `true`.

Comment: `==` has nothing to do with hash codes.

Comment: So why its returing false ..can you please explain

Answer (score 1):

`==` compares references.

`.equals` compares values.

When you are comparing values of objects, for example, `String`s, you should always use `s1.equals(s2)`

When you are comparing references to objects to compare if two references are pointing to the *same* object. Then you should use `==`.

---

In your code, `System.out.println(s1==s2); //returns false` this statement compares two references `s1` and `s2` which are pointing to different objects though their values are same (value is "Hello", but they are two different objects in memory). Thus, your get a `false` in your output.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: but S1.hashcode and S2.hashcode is same..

Comment: if you look at the code for `String.hashcode()` method, you'll find that the hashcode is computed by using the value contained in the string. So, if two strings have the same value, their hashcodes will be same.

Comment: What my assumption was If the string already exists in the pool, a reference to the pooled instance is returned. If string doesn't exist in the pool, a new string instance is created and placed in the pool. For example:

String s1="Welcome";  
String s2="Welcome";//will not create new instance

Comment: That assumption is correct. The only difference in your post is that your are invoking the `new String("hello")` constructor for `s1`.

Comment: When you call `String.intern()`, it returns the reference to the object from the Stirng pool.